# UFW firewall rules for transmission-daemon on ubuntu 20.XX

Tags: ubuntu, firewall, vps, ufw, bittorrent

I have got transmission running on ubuntu 20.XX VPS and i can log into the web interface with MYIP:9091/ to manage the files.

I am using ufw firewall. I have added these rules to allow the following ports:

- 22/tcp (OpenSSH)           ALLOW IN    Anywhere
- 20/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
- 21/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
- 40000:50000/tcp            ALLOW IN    Anywhere
- 990/tcp                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere
- 6688/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere
- 28967/tcp                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere
- 9091                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere
- 5432 on eth1               ALLOW IN    Anywhere
- 9091/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere
- 22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
- 2222                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere
- 80/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
- 80                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere
- 443/tcp                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere
- 443                        ALLOW IN    Anywhere
- 6000:6003/tcp              ALLOW IN    Anywhere
- 6000:6003/udp              ALLOW IN    Anywhere
- 49152:65535/udp            ALLOW IN    Anywhere
- 49152:65535/tcp            ALLOW IN    Anywhere
- 9091/udp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere
- 22/tcp (OpenSSH (v6))      ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
- 20/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
- 21/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
- 40000:50000/tcp (v6)       ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
- 990/tcp (v6)               ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
- 6688/tcp (v6)              ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
- 28967/tcp (v6)             ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
- 9091 (v6)                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
- 5432 (v6) on eth1          ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
- 9091/tcp (v6)              ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
- 22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
- 2222 (v6)                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
- 80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
- 80 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
- 443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
- 443 (v6)                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
- 6000:6003/tcp (v6)         ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
- 6000:6003/udp (v6)         ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
- 49152:65535/udp (v6)       ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
- 49152:65535/tcp (v6)       ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
- 9091/udp (v6)              ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)

When I do `sudo ufw enable` transmission web interface is no longer available. When I then do `sudo ufw disable` it's back again, so it's a ufw problem.

Any ideas what ports I'm missing or what is misconfigured?

Answer (score 0):

Seem you've enabled everything, may you check if the Transmission has the [AppArmor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1024399/block-process-from-using-port) configuration and the port 9091 is allowed?

If you have any http deamon (apache/nginx), you can configure it and proxy-pass on your Transmission port, it shall work as the http daemon has the AppArmor.

When you enable the FW, is port 22 acessible? Maybe flush the UFW configuration and and only 80/443 and than the 9091, it shall give you the hint where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the issue was, I didn't add the transmission listening port, it works fine now.